# Python Multiprocessing: The child process finished but did not join

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I try to implement a multiprocessing code for generating some dictionary interested.

Here is my logic:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager, Queue, Process

input_list = Queue()
for x in my_input:  # my_input is my input data
  input_list.put(x)

output = Manager().dict()

def job():
  while input_list.qsize()>0:
    x = input_list.get()
    result = my_func(x)  # Do something here
    output[x] = result

def monitor():
  while True:
    if input_list.qsize() > 0:
      time.sleep(1)
      print("Item List is Empty")
      print("Does all the result being save?", len(output.keys()) == len(my_input))

job_list = [Process(target=monitor)]
for _ in range(num_of_worker):
  job_list.append(Process(target=job))
for j in job_list:
  j.start()
for j in job_list:
  j.join()

print("The script is finished")
```

The logic of my code is quite simple.

- Initialize a queue and put my input in.
- Define two functions, `job` (doing something and save it to a dict) and `monitor` (print when everything inside queue is being processed and print how many results are being saved).
- Then standard multiprocessing `start` and `join`.

The output I am getting:

```
Item List is Empty
Does all the result being save? True
...
```

Some child process did not finish and not yet join.
The script is stuck here and did not print "The script is finished".

My script will get stuck at the `join` statement, despite the monitor telling me that everything is finished (by checking number of items left in `input_list` and number of results stored in `output`).

Moreover, this error is not replicable. If I see my script stuck for more than 5 minutes, I will terminate it manually and restart it. I found that the script could finish properly (like 3 out of 10 times).

What could be happening?

Remark:
Since I suspect the error is some child process did not join, I tried something with `Event`. When the monitor found that the `input_list` is empty and `output` is completely filled, it will kill all the process. But the script is also stuck at the event triggering. (And same as above, the code does not get stuck every time, it works 3 out of 10 times).

Comment: You have a race condition between checking the queue size and acquiring an element. Another process may overtake you there and take the last element. Then one (or more) processes get stuck trying to get an element. Use ```get_nowait()```

Answer (score 0):

@Homer512 comments gives me insight on wher is the mistake in the code.

switch from

```
def job():
   while input_list.qsize>0:
      x = input_list.get()
      ...
```

to

```
def job():
       while input_list.qsize>0:
          try:
            x = input_list.get(True,5)
            ...
          except Empty:
            return 0
```

The reason for my script stuck at join because when `input_list` got only 1 element left, it trigger the while statement of `job` but only one process can get something from the queue. The other process will just stuck at `get` without suitable timeout.